# Get roots field of a document firestore python

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore

So I have a firestore database that look something like this :

```
collection1
collection2
collection3-----Doc1
           -----Doc2----Map1 (contain multiple fields)
                    ----Map2 (contain multiple fields)
```

What I want is to retrieve `Map1` and `Map2` fields name first (to put it into a `selectfield`), then the fields that each map contain (they will be display when the name of the corresponding map is selected)

Anybody have a clue on how to do that? Thanks for reading!

#### TL;DR

I want to retrieve fields name that are at a doc root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like following:

```
// get the collection3
const collections = firestore.collection('collection3').get()

// get all documents
const documents = shopSnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());

console.log(documents);

// iterate over the documents and print to the screen the every document ID
for(var i=0; i<documents.length; i++){
    console.log(documents[i].id);
```